# Why can't I access App.js from javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I redirected my react App.js to a different homepage like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
     <div className="App">
          <BrowserRouter>
           <Route exact path="/" render={() => {window.location.href="etv/indextv.html"}} />
           </BrowserRouter>

....
```

It's working, the homepage appears. Now I want it to go back to this React file once the function is called on a buttonclick. (this is basically a react js and a js project calling each other).

I tried adding this path in the html file:

```
<script src = "../../src/App.js"></script>
```

And this is the function that should call the App again on a button click. (It would probably go in circles, but I just want to be able to call the App.js file again, for now it's calling the App() function in it).

```
function startMessage() {
    App();
}
```

I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined`, so it can't see the function probably.

The directories are set up like this:

```
combinedtest/public/etv/indextv.html
combinedtest/src/App.js
```

I also get an error for some reason:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on App.js:1

**EDIT:** I solved the problem quite simply. I added this single line to the javascript function instead of trying to call the App:

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/messages';
```

Since the code checks if the path is "/", redirecting it anywhere else(/messages) actually directs it to the original React project anyways.

Comment: Because that is JSX not JavaScript.  You have to use a transpiler.  Are you using create-react-app?  See also [React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html).

Comment: React file is not something that a browser can render by itself. Also App is a react component. Calling it won't make it appear somewhere in the site. You need to mount it on a DOM element.

Comment: Have you tried reloading  your React application by navigating back from the `indextv.html` to the `index.html` found in the public folder?

Comment: why can you not just go back a page in history or redirect to the page like `/` where your app is hosted?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I edited the answer. The solution was rather simple. Hopefully I won't run into further issues.